# What is the name of this window function?

Tags: mathematics, windows, functions

Is there a common name for this window function?

I made it to replace a Hann window used in loading an FFT.

It is basically a wide lobe cosine tapered window, or negative Blackman window. Is there a better more common name?

$y = 0.5 * (1.25 - \cos(\pi * 2 * {x \over N}) - (0.25 * \cos(\pi * 4 * {x \over N})))$

$N$ is the total number of samples.

[image]